# "Type variable is ambiguous" with Persistent in Haskell Yesod

Tags: haskell, type-inference, yesod, persistent, typechecking

I'm trying to use Persistent with Yesod to get the list of all field keys from a table in my database. My accessor code is as follows:

```
getMapList :: Handler [Text]
getMapList = runDB $ do
  dbList <- selectList [] []
  return (map getMapName dbList)
  where getMapName (Entity (Key (PersistText mapName)) _)  = mapName
```

Note that this is a game: "Map" here is a map in the game sense, not in the Haskell sense.

I get the following error, which indicates that the type inference engine can't figure out my types, based on which database backend I'm using.

```
Handler/Create.hs:101:13:
Couldn't match type `PersistEntityBackend t0'
              with `persistent-1.2.3.0:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend'
The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Expected type: PersistMonadBackend (SqlPersistT (HandlerT App IO))
  Actual type: PersistEntityBackend t0
In a stmt of a 'do' block: dbList <- selectList [] []
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { dbList <- selectList [] [];
        return (map getMapName dbList) }'
In the expression:
  runDB
  $ do { dbList <- selectList [] [];
         return (map getMapName dbList) }
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? What do I need to add to the type signature to get this to type-check properly? Thanks!

EDIT: My model is defined as such:

```
GameMap
    mapName Text
    mapCode Text
    UniqueGameMap mapName
    deriving Typeable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need add the Filter type signature, which is based on the table you defined elsewhere (I am not sure if you were trying to avoid needing to type in the column names somewhere though....  I am not sure if this is possible).

Does this work for you?  If the table is defined as-

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
KingsLadiesInWaiting
    name String
    skillLevel Int
    deriving Show
|]
```

just add-

```
getMapList :: Handler [T.Text]
getMapList = runDB $ do
  dbList <- selectList ([]::[Filter (KingsLadiesInWaitingGeneric backend)]) []
  return (map getMapName dbList)
  where getMapName (Entity (Key (PersistText mapName)) _)  = mapName
```

When I did this it compiled.

This should make for an interesting game!

Comment: I tried that with with GameMapGeneric instead of KingsLadiesInWaitingGenerc, and I get the following error: Not in scope: type constructor or class `GameMapGeneric'. Is there something in particular I would need to import? I'm using a scaffolded site, so I've got this spread out over a bunch of files, my handlers are each in their own file.

Comment: When you run "yesod init" it should have created a file called Model.hs, which you need to import in the file with the function.  The actual models should be in config/models, so you can also verify that the table "GameMap" exists.

Comment: I still get the error, and when I do "import Model (GameMapGeneric)" I get "Module 'Model' does not export `GameMapGeneric'". Any thoughts? Thanks so much for all the help so far.

Comment: Good/Bad news....  The good news is- I inspected the data types created by Model.hs using "ghc --show-iface Model.hi", and was able to find the actual type created (It was just the table name without the word Generic at the end).  It ran.  The bad news is, the output isn't what you expected it to be.  It isn't the column name, but the column value.  I might play around some more and try to find if there is another way to get column names.

Comment: Got it sorted out, it's a bit of a hack but I added a trivial condition to the list of selection filters , instead of [], and that was enough for the typechecker to figure it all out.